# Non-greedy newline character match with re.DOTALL

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to reproduce this regex in Python: https://regex101.com/r/tP1bS4/2

A sample `entry` data is like this:

```
[ 10.0.7.58/54648 -> 31.221.26.40/80 (http response) ]-
|
| server   = 31.221.26.40/80
| app      = ???
| lang     = none
| params   = anonymous
| raw_sig  = 1:Content-Type,?Last-Modified,?Cache-Control,?Expires,Date,Connection=[keep-alive]:Keep-Alive,Accept-Ranges:
|
```

Essentially I want to end up with one group with two elements: the server IP and port, from the third line.

Here's my Python attempt;

```
server = re.findall( '\| server[ \s]+= (.*)\/(.*)\n', entry, re.DOTALL)
print server
```

Which gives me this `server` group:

```
[('31.221.26.40', '80\n| app      = ???\n| lang     = none\n| params   = anonymous\n| raw_sig  = 1:Content-Type,?Last-Modified,?Cache-Control,?Expires,Date,Connection=[keep-alive]:Keep-Alive,Accept-Ranges:\n|')]
```

As you can see it's not splitting on the `\n`. Expected result would be:

```
[('31.221.26.40', '80')]
```

Comment: If you remove DOTALL, it should work as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it does work, why is that though?

Comment: Because a `.` with DOTALL matches a newline. Your pattern is inefficient anyway. It should be `server = re.findall(r'\| server\s+= ([^/]*)/(\d+)', entry)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! I've actually solved it with `\| server[ \s]+= (.*)\/(.*?)\n` now knowing that, although for this case yours works just as well.

Comment: That pattern is again very bad... But you can use it if you think it is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not really an experienced coder, I just dabble around. But out of curiosity, why is it bad?

Comment: Because `.*` matches `/` and all up to the end of line, then backtracking occurs to find `/`, and the engine looks for the `/`, fails, retries, fails.... If the string is short, it is OK. It is bad practice to rely on dot matching if you can avoid it.

Comment: You could probably do a split on `\n` and then iterate over each item of a list and find the server ip and port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me clear out some things. `re.DOTALL` modifier makes a `.` symbol match *any* symbol including a newline. The `.*` subpattern with DOTALL matches the string up to the end.

If you use `'\| server[ \s]+= (.*)\/(.*)\n'`, the first `.*` matches up to the last `/` and the second `.*` matches up to the last `\n` because it is greedy (that is, the engine grabs all the rest of the string and then backtracks trying to accommodate for the subsequent subpatterns).

As your data are on 1 single line, you *do not* want to make `.` match a newline. Thus, the easiest way to solve the problem is using

```
server = re.findall(r'\|\s*server\s*=\s*(.*?)/(.*)', entry)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS1tV7/1)

However, dot matching is only good when we do not know what characters to expect. You can enhance the regex using character classes:

```
server = re.findall(r'\|\s*server\s*=\s*([^\s/]+)/(\d+)', entry)
```

Another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS1tV7/2) (note the efficiency increased x2 times)

The `([^\s/]+)` matches 1 or more characters other than whitespace and `/` and `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.

Comment: fantastic!- it took time to know you since you are with new name!

Comment: @SIslam: It is the same, just another transliteration scheme + the first name.

Answer (score 2):

I would try-

```
re.findall(r'\| server[ \s]+= (.*)\/([^\/\W]*)',string)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP1bS4/3)

More robust with space normalization  `\|\s*server\s*=\s*([^/]*?)/([^/\W]*)`

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
import io

data = '''[ 10.0.7.58/54648 -> 31.221.26.40/80 (http response) ]-
|
| server   = 31.221.26.40/80
| app      = ???
| lang     = none
| params   = anonymous
| raw_sig  = 1:Content-Type,?Last-Modified,?Cache-Control,?Expires,Date,Connection=[keep-alive]:Keep-Alive,Accept-Ranges:
|'''


for line in io.StringIO(data):
    if line.startswith('| server '):
        print(line[13:].rstrip().split('/'))
```

If you don't know exactly the number of spaces or tabs after "server", you can change it like this:

```
if line.startswith('| server'):
    print(line.split()[3].split('/'))
```